# Composite relation of R

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm new to relations in discrete mathematics and I am having a hard time understanding how to do this exercise.

Let $R$ be a binary relation on the set of integers such that $(a,b) \in R$ if and only if $b-a=1$. What is the composite relation $R \circ R$?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: See [Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations#Definition): $(a,c) \in R \circ R \text {  iff  } (\exists b \ (a,b) \in R \text { and } (b,c) \in R)$.

Answer (score 0):

The composite relation $R \circ R$ consists of those pairs $(a,c)$ such that there is a $b$ where $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ are both members of $R$.  Suppose I give you a number $a$.  How many pairs $(a,b) \in R?$

Comment: To me it seems logical that there is as many pairs of $(a,b) \in R$ that there is elements in R

Comment: That is correct, but I was asking for a specific $a$. how many pairs are in $R$

Comment: Since $R$ is an infinite set I would think there would be an infinite number of pairs

Comment: I was trying to suggest you think about how many pairs there were with a given first element, leading to the solution Hagen von Eitzen gave.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $a\mathrel{(R\circ R)}b$ iff there exists $c$ with $a\mathrel R c$ and $c\mathrel R b$, The latter means $c-a=1$ and $b-c=1$, hence $b-a=2$. We conclude that $a\mathrel{(R\circ R)} b$ iff $b-a=2$ - at least provided that in our underlying set, we always have $a+1$ in int whenever $a$ and $a+2$ are in it!